# Gradle transitive dependencies of a subproject used in another subproject

Tags: scala, gradle

I have the following build structure:

```
rootProject
    |--> subProjectA
        |--> dependencies(someDependantJar-1.0.jar)
    |
    |--> subProjectB
        |--> dependencies(subProjectA)
```

in **subProjectB**, I have the following declaration for Scala because my Scala depends upon external JAR's from **subProjectA**, as well as it needs to compile first because my Java compilation is dependent on my scala code (not the other way around):

```
apply plugin: 'scala'

compileScala.taskDependencies.values = compileScala.taskDependencies.values - 'compileJava'
compileJava.dependsOn compileScala

sourceSets {
    main {
        scala {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
        }
    }
}
```

When I run:

```
subProjectB:compileScala
```

I get compilation issues with **subProjectB** not finding the classes in someDependantJar-1.0.jar from **subProjectA**.

When I run:

```
println '___ dependencies ________________________________________________'
configurations.compile.dependencies.each { dep -> println dep.name }
println '__________________________________________________________________'
```

I get the following list of dependencies:

```
    ___ dependencies ________________________________________________
    commons-lang
    [omit for brevity]
    subProjectA
    __________________________________________________________________
```

So I dont see someDependantJar-1.0.jar and was hoping that someone can shed light on this issue so I dont have to define the transitive dependencies in subProjectA and subProjectB (duplicate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you havn't defined a compile dependency in subProjectB.
Not sure if i got your setup correctly, I think you need to add the dependency to someDependantJar? an you try adding a dependency in projectB on projectA

```
configurations{
    compile ":someDependentJar:1.0"
}
```

cheers,
René

Comment: Ugg. Not the end of the world, but was hoping it would be automatic.